# Prefix.pch ReactiveCocoa/RACEXTScope.h file not found error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

As mentioned in the title, I have 
`ReactiveCocoa/RACEXTScope.h` file not found error in `Prefix.pch` file.

The following is Pod file

```
platform :ios, "7.1"

pod 'Parse-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.2'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3'
pod 'ReactiveViewModel', '~> 0.2'
pod 'Parse-RACExtensions', '~> 0.0'
pod 'CKCalendar', '~> 1.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.6'
```

As you can see from images, the file exists.
But there is not interface declaration in the file.
Does that matter?

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

[image: Error message]
[image: RACEXTScope.h file]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

At the top of your podfile write this line:

```
link_with  ['ProjectName', 'ProjectNameTests']
```

install pod, and at your project Build Setting->Other Linker Flags, add `$(inherited)`.

That happened because Tests couldn't find pods.

Answer (score 0):

solution for me was replace in podfile string     pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3'     with    pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3.1'
because in cocoapods.org not updated info https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWznK.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it.
In XCode go to the `Build Settings` -> search `Header Search Paths` and change the `${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ReactiveCocoa` to `recursive` from `non-recursive`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y04YY.png