# Panel sliding from the bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I want to implement panel, that by default appears from the bottom only by 1/4.
And when i tap on this part, or swipe it, it should roll out on full screen.

exactly what i want was implemented in this [app](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/andeks.metro/id392589075?mt=8)

So what i tried already:
Making UIView and trying to apply tap and swipe gestures. UIView didn't catch it. But it caught touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc.
UITableView. Same.
Making UIViewController. Ended without any idea how to handle it to right way.

So any ideas or links are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check PPRevealSideViewController https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController, I think you can find what you need.
When you tap on the new viewController you can change the Offset.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
main = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewControllerr"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];
_revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];
_revealSideViewController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = _revealSideViewController;
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
-(void)popViewController{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PoppedViewController *pvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PoppedViewController"];
    [self.revealSideViewController pushViewController:pvc onDirection:PPRevealSideDirectionBottom withOffset:_offset animated:_animated completion:nil];
}
```

**PoppedViewController.m**

```
-viewDidLoad{
    //...
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(getFullView)];
    gesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

-getFullView{
    [self.revealSideViewController changeOffset:0.0f forDirection:PPRevealSideDirectionLeft];
}
```

Comment: when i try to setup (after installing pod), i am getting <PPHelpMe/PPHelpMe.h> file not found. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, maybe you didn't write proper the podfile. Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970560/prefix-pch-reactivecocoa-racextscope-h-file-not-found-error/26162228#26162228

Comment: Didn't work. I write in pod 'link_with  ['test', 'testTests']
platform :ios 
pod 'PPRevealSideViewController', '~> 1.1'. Because 1.2.1 aren't installing.

Comment: Solved. Podfile should be like this. `target 'appName' do <br/>
  <tab>pod 'PPRevealSideViewController', '~> 1.2.2'<br/>
end`

Comment: I m glad you found the solution eventually. Well, in every project of mine I write the podfile in the below way and there's no problem:

    `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '7.1'
    pod 'PPRevealSideViewController', '~> 1.2'`